# How to make / provoke a php error in php error log?

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to see if my `php_error.log` file works but I don't know how to produce an error that will show up in the log file.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php 
asd();
?>
```

save this and open it as webpage

Error should be like

```
[Thu Mar 29 10:28:41 2012] [error] [client 106.132.155.92] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function asd() in * on line 2
[Thu Mar 29 10:28:41 2012] [error] [client 106.132.155.92] PHP Stack trace:
[Thu Mar 29 10:28:41 2012] [error] [client 106.132.155.92] PHP   1. {main}() *:0
```

Answer (score 5):

Try Using

```
 error_log("I Love error", 0);
```

See more documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);    
echo =>
```

it will create error like

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in *filename* 
on line *line number*
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
error_log("This is the error message written to the log", 0);
```