# PHP error reporting destination: error log file vs. web page

Tags: php, error-log

In the following code, I get the 'AAA' on the web page output (only), while the 'BBB' goes to the error.log file (only).
I want **both** to go to the error.log file, so the user doesn't see potential errors while I do. How?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('error_log','error.log');
error_reporting(-1); // all
trigger_error('AAA');
error_log('BBB');
?>
```

(Note: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921643/how-to-make-provoke-an-php-error-in-php-error-log but not the same.)

Comment: The concept of trigger_error is in the User level. "trigger_error — Generates a user-level error/warning/notice message". If that's the case you're using it wrong.

Comment: So how can I test that "appropriate" potential errors go to my error.log file, **without** using the 'error_log' function?

Comment: You can create a custom error handler. but may I ask why "without using the error_log", it's its purpose after all.

Comment: "errors go to my error.log file without using the error_log" means -- I want to know about errors that I don't expect: Calling an non-existing function, syntax error, runtime errors -- but I don't want the user to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

OR

Create your own error handler function and add it before calling `trigger_error` function with [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) function.

> This function can be used for defining your own way of handling errors
>   during runtime, for example in applications in which you need to do
>   cleanup of data/files when a critical error happens, or when you need
>   to trigger an error under certain conditions (using trigger_error()).